# Who can it belong to? fossil tooth

Tags: fossils

[image]

**Tooth was found in Baltic Sea, near Lithuanian coast, **

Comment: This looks far more like a horn coral or plant segment than tooth to me.  Long shot would be more of a horn than tooth, but the striation yells coral.  Lack of a tooth root and a ridge line would indicate to me there never was such a structure.  I think we all see tooth at first glance, but the pattern is wrong to me.

Comment: I agree definitely not a tooth, the surface is all wrong, you may want to change the title to get some people who are better at identifying corals.

Comment: Last week found another one in Melnragė.[![coral horn or Stone fossil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoGeG.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoGeG.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

The geology of Lithuania is pretty complex - ice ages could have brought  nearly anything. The fossil belongs to Rugose corals - an extinct order of solitary and colonial corals that were abundant in Middle Ordovician to Late Permian seas.

For precise identification try Baltoscandia fossil database: http://fossiilid.info/46